# Getting Error for Python Environment, can install any packages

Tags: python, windows, pip, package, environment

[enter image description here][1]

[enter image description here][2]/i.stack.imgur.com/AvIjG.png

**strong text**
[1]: https:/
[2]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToG2F.png**`strong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToG2F.png**%60strong) text`**

Comment: Please post the code you tried to run, and the error that you got, as text rather than an image.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is result of using VPN or any IP changer. just turn it off. or update your pip using

> C:\Python310\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

or it is because of python version you use. you can install python version 3.9 because as I experienced before, python version 3.10 does not support some packages because they have not release for it yet.

I hope it become helpful